# JPanel which one of Listeners is proper for visibility is changed

Tags: java, swing, listener, jpanel, jcomponent

Are there some rules, or good/bad experiences with `AncestorListener`, `ComponentListener` or `HierarchyListener` listening for visibility of changes with `JPanel` and `JComponents`?

Is one of them better or safer than the others? I would especially like to know about when and how `JPanel` / `JComponent` is hidden.

Notice the following code contains incorrect Swing rules, like using `Thread.sleep(int)`, in this case, to allow me to print-out correct order of `Listeners` in Swing GUI

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

public class CardlayoutTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CardLayout card = new CardLayout();

    public CardlayoutTest() {
        JPanel pnlA = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlA.add(new JButton("A"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel pnlB = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlB.add(new JButton("B"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel pnlC = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnlC.add(new JButton("C"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(card);
        add(pnlA, "A");
        add(pnlB, "B");
        add(pnlC, "C");

        pnlA.addAncestorListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlB.addAncestorListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlC.addAncestorListener(new EventHandler());

        pnlA.addHierarchyListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlB.addHierarchyListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlB.addHierarchyListener(new EventHandler());

        pnlA.addComponentListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlB.addComponentListener(new EventHandler());
        pnlB.addComponentListener(new EventHandler());
    }

    class EventHandler implements AncestorListener, ComponentListener, HierarchyListener {

        @Override
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.EventHandler.ancestorAdded()");
        }

        @Override
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.EventHandler.ancestorMoved()");
        }

        @Override
        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.EventHandler.ancestorRemoved()");
        }

        @Override
        public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Components Change: " + e.getChanged());
            if ((e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0) {
                if (e.getComponent().isDisplayable()) {
                    System.out.println("Components DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED : " + e.getChanged());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Components DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED : " + e.getChanged());
                }
            }
            if ((e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0) {
                if (e.getComponent().isDisplayable()) {
                    System.out.println("Components SHOWING_CHANGED : " + e.getChanged());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Components SHOWING_CHANGED : " + e.getChanged());
                }
            }
        }

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Hidden");
        }

        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Moved");
        }

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Resized ");
        }

        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + " --- Shown");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardlayoutTest t = new CardlayoutTest();
        t.setSize(500, 500);
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ FIRST");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "A");
        t.setVisible(true);
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ SECOND");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "B");
        System.out.print("\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("CardlayoutTest.main()------------------------ THIRD");
        t.card.show(t.getContentPane(), "C");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to listen EXACTLY the visibility changes - use `ComponentListener` or `ComponentAdapter`:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    panel.addComponentListener ( new ComponentAdapter ()
    {
        public void componentShown ( ComponentEvent e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Component shown" );
        }

        public void componentHidden ( ComponentEvent e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Component hidden" );
        }
    } );
```

But that visibility might not be the one you think about. `isVisible()` flag will be `true` even if the `Component` is not added to any `Container` and hence not showing at all!

That visibility a has a slightly different purpose.  You can use it to manually hide the `Component` that is already added and shown somewhere in your application. In that case, (if you use `setVisible(false)`) it will become hidden and every `ComponentListener` of that `Component` will be informed about that change.

So, talking about actual visibility...

This is what you should use to listen to **actual** component appearance/disappearance:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    panel.addAncestorListener ( new AncestorListener ()
    {
        public void ancestorAdded ( AncestorEvent event )
        {
            // Component added somewhere
        }

        public void ancestorRemoved ( AncestorEvent event )
        {
            // Component removed from container
        }

        public void ancestorMoved ( AncestorEvent event )
        {
            // Component container moved
        }
    } );
```

I always use that listener to determine when the `Component` is added somewhere and also to listen when it is moved/removed.

Also, you can always check if the `Component` is actually visible to application user by calling `isShowing()` method:

```
boolean userCanSeeThePanel = panel.isShowing();
```

This will return `true` ONLY if that panel is added to VISIBLE to user frame and `isVisible()` flag is also true (it is usually `true`, unless you set it to `false`).

I guess that's all I can tell you about visibility. I might have misunderstood your question.  Correct me if I am wrong in that case.

Comment: @mKorbel Feel free to ask more if you still don't understand some part of the visiblity. It is a pretty tricky part of Swing actually

Comment: basically interesting me to catch proper events when already visible JComponent is (change to) hidden

Comment: If the change is made by "setVisible(false)" method - use ComponentListener or ComponentAdapter. In "componentHidden" you will recieve notification when component is hidden ("setVisible(false)" called) and in "componentShown" when it is shown ("setVisible(true)" called)

Comment: till this moment is everything clear as demonstrated my SSCCE, all three Listener fired expected events,

Comment: So, whats the question then? You are using proper listeners for proper events... i guess there is nothing more to say in such case. Or you have found some other problem?

Comment: `So, whats the question then? :)` hehehe your answer is most complex with clear description, we need to be patient, maybe someone will kill my and your posts here, with wrong experiences, maybe yes, maybe not :-)

Comment: accepting your very good for AncesorListener, works together with RepaintManager exception (my simple and reduced test)