# Java swing - one searchbox for multiple tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, jtabbedpane

I want to have a GUI application which would contain multiple tabs, each with its own Table. I would like to include a search box below the tabs which would filter the **currently selected tab**. How can this dynamic behaviour be achieved?

Comment: question whats happens with value in "searchbox" in case that in "searchbox" was typed any value and you'll switch to another tab ???

Comment: where exactly is the problem (except a little logic, as @mKorbel noted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. figure one you can to share `RowSorter/RowFilter` for all `JTables` in current JVM instance

   - filtering works for all `JTables`
   - notice there could be performance issue in the case that there is/are JTable(s) contains bunch of rows
   - quite possible for `JTables` that contains a few (limited number of) rows together
2. determine (from arrays of tabs) visible tab, [visible JComponents(or have to look at SwingUtilities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed), then remove  `RowSorter/RowFilter` from all `JTables` instances and then to add `RowSorter/RowFilter` to the visible an focusable `JTable`
3. `JTextField` for `RowSorter/RowFilter` should be crated only once times