# JPanel added but not displayed "in time"

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jfreechart, event-dispatch-thread

I have a JFrame that displays JPanels depending on the MenuItem you click. It works, but now I need to call a method once a JPanel is added to the frame and it is being shown (because I'm using JFreeChart inside that panel and I have to call `chartPanel.repaint()` when the JPanel is visible):

```
this.getContentPane().add( myjpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER ); //this = JFrame
this.validate();
myjpanel.methodCalledOnceDisplayed();
```

Does it seem ok? Is `myjpanel` being shown really? It seems it is not:

```
public void methodCalledOnceDisplayed() {
    chartPanel.repaint()
}
```

This is not working (`chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0)` is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException). That means that the JPanel was not visible when repaint was called, I've tested the following:

```
public void methodCalledOnceDisplayed() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You should see myjpanel now");
    chartPanel.repaint()
}
```

Now it works, I see `myjpanel` behind the alert, just as expected, chartPanel is repainted and no Exception occurs.

**EDIT**: SSCCE (jfreechart and jcommon needed: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window frame = new Window();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Window() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton clickme = new JButton("Click me");
        clickme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                contentPane.removeAll();
                MyJPanel mypanel = new MyJPanel();
                contentPane.add( mypanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
                validate();
                mypanel.methodCalledOnceDisplayed();
            }
        });
        contentPane.add( clickme, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        JPanel example = new JPanel();
        example.add( new JLabel("Example JPanel") );
        contentPane.add( example, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    }

}

class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements ChartMouseListener {
    private ChartPanel chartPanel;
    private JFreeChart chart;
    private XYPlot subplotTop;
    private XYPlot subplotBottom;
    private CombinedDomainXYPlot plot;

    public MyJPanel() {
        this.add( new JLabel("This JPanel contains the chart") );
        createCombinedChart();
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(this);
        this.add( chartPanel );
    }

    private void createCombinedChart() {    
        plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot();
        plot.setGap(30);
        createSubplots();
        plot.add(subplotTop, 4);
        plot.add(subplotBottom, 1);
        plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

        chart = new JFreeChart("Title", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,20), plot, true);
    }

    private void createSubplots() {
        subplotTop = new XYPlot();
        subplotBottom = new XYPlot();

        subplotTop.setDataset(emptyDataset("Empty 1"));
        subplotBottom.setDataset(emptyDataset("Empty 2"));
    }

    private XYDataset emptyDataset( String title ) {
        TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries(title);
        TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        tsc.addSeries(ts);
        return tsc;
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse moved!");
    }
    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {}

    public void methodCalledOnceDisplayed() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Magic!"); //try to comment this line and see the console
        chartPanel.repaint();
        //now we can get chart areas
        this.chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0).getDataArea();
        this.chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(1).getDataArea();
    }
}
```

See what happens with and without the JOptionPane.

Comment: _I'm using JFreeChart inside that panel and I have to call_ `chartPanel.repaint()` _when the_ `JPanel` _is visible_. Why? `ChartPanel` listens to `JFreeChart`. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. Also consider [`CardPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An *explanation* of why is this happening would be great.

You may get some insight from the variation below. Note

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT) for the reason suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13411868/230513).
- The EDT continues to process events, as shown in the example, even while user interaction is limited to the modal dialog.
- Invoking `repaint()` should *not* be required when using `ChartPanel`.
- Prefer [`CardLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) or [`JTabbedPane`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) over manual container manipulation.
- Rather than invoking `setPreferredSize()`, override `getPreferredSize()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Addendum: *You have removed the two lines … that are showing the problem.*

`ChartRenderingInfo` is dynamic data that doesn't exist until the chart has been rendered. The modal dialog handles events while the chart is updated in the background; without it, you can schedule your method by wrapping it in a `Runnable` suitable for `invokeLater()`:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myPanel.methodCalledOnceDisplayed();
    }
});
```

A better scheme is to access the `ChartRenderingInfo` in listeners where you *know* the data is valid, i.e. listeners implemented by `ChartPanel`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
* @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513
*/
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final MyJPanel myPanel = new MyJPanel();
        panel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return myPanel.getPreferredSize();
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel);

        myPanel.start();
        JButton clickme = new JButton("Click me");
        clickme.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                validate();
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myPanel.methodCalledOnceDisplayed();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        panel.add(clickme, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel example = new JPanel();
        example.add(new JLabel("Example JPanel"));
        panel.add(example, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final Random r = new Random();
        private ChartPanel chartPanel;
        private JFreeChart chart;
        private XYPlot subplotTop;
        private XYPlot subplotBottom;
        private CombinedDomainXYPlot plot;
        private Timer timer;
        private Day now = new Day(new Date());

        public MyJPanel() {
            this.add(new JLabel("Chart panel"));
            createCombinedChart();
            chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            this.add(chartPanel);
            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    update(subplotTop);
                    update(subplotBottom);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        private void update(XYPlot plot) {
            TimeSeriesCollection t = (TimeSeriesCollection) plot.getDataset();
            for (int i = 0; i < t.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
                TimeSeries s = t.getSeries(i);
                s.add(now, Math.abs(r.nextGaussian()));
                now = (Day) now.next();
            }
        }

        private void createCombinedChart() {
            plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot();
            plot.setGap(30);
            createSubplots();
            plot.add(subplotTop, 4);
            plot.add(subplotBottom, 1);
            plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
            chart = new JFreeChart("Title",
                JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
            plot.setDomainAxis(new DateAxis("Domain"));
        }

        private void createSubplots() {
            subplotTop = new XYPlot();
            subplotBottom = new XYPlot();
            subplotTop.setDataset(emptyDataset("Set 1"));
            subplotTop.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
            subplotTop.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Range"));
            subplotBottom.setDataset(emptyDataset("Set 2"));
            subplotBottom.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
            subplotBottom.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Range"));
        }

        private XYDataset emptyDataset(String title) {
            TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
            TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries(title);
            tsc.addSeries(ts);
            return tsc;
        }

        public void methodCalledOnceDisplayed() {
            PlotRenderingInfo plotInfo =
                this.chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < plotInfo.getSubplotCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(plotInfo.getSubplotInfo(i).getDataArea());
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Magic!");
        }
    }
}
```

Addendum: One additional iteration to illustrate `ChartMouseListener` and clean up a few loose ends.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartMouseListener;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.entity.ChartEntity;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test t = new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final MyJPanel myPanel = new MyJPanel();
        f.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        myPanel.start();
    }

    private static class MyJPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final Random r = new Random();
        private ChartPanel chartPanel;
        private JFreeChart chart;
        private XYPlot subplotTop;
        private XYPlot subplotBottom;
        private CombinedDomainXYPlot plot;
        private Timer timer;
        private Day now = new Day(new Date());

        public MyJPanel() {
            createCombinedChart();
            chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            this.add(chartPanel);
            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    update(subplotTop);
                    update(subplotBottom);
                    now = (Day) now.next();
                }
            });
            chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
                    final ChartEntity entity = e.getEntity();
                    System.out.println(entity + " " + entity.getArea());
                }

                @Override
                public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        private void update(XYPlot plot) {
            TimeSeriesCollection t = (TimeSeriesCollection) plot.getDataset();
            for (int i = 0; i < t.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
                TimeSeries s = t.getSeries(i);
                s.add(now, Math.abs(r.nextGaussian()));
            }
        }

        private void createCombinedChart() {
            plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot();
            createSubplots();
            plot.add(subplotTop, 4);
            plot.add(subplotBottom, 1);
            plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
            chart = new JFreeChart("Title",
                JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
            plot.setDomainAxis(new DateAxis("Domain"));
        }

        private void createSubplots() {
            subplotTop = new XYPlot();
            subplotBottom = new XYPlot();
            subplotTop.setDataset(emptyDataset("Set 1"));
            subplotTop.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
            subplotTop.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Range"));
            subplotBottom.setDataset(emptyDataset("Set 2"));
            subplotBottom.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
            subplotBottom.setRangeAxis(new NumberAxis("Range"));
        }

        private XYDataset emptyDataset(String title) {
            TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
            TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries(title);
            tsc.addSeries(ts);
            return tsc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but you have removed the two lines `chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().....;` that are showing the problem. I need those lines, as they give me two rectangles that I use to calculate the coordinates of the mouse relative to the plot. The question is why those lines work when the JOptionPane is shown, and not if the JOptionPane is removed?

Comment: _You have removed the two lines … that are showing the problem._ It's a gift! :-) More above.

Comment: Those screens bring tears to my eyes oh the beauty :) +1

Comment: So much for my plan to give up eye candy for Lent. :-)

Comment: Thank you both @mKorbel and trashgod for the answers. I will accept this one, I like your magic :)

Comment: @trashgod Hi, Can you help me please with similar situation, I can't fix it... https://stackoverflow.com/q/54623741/5113188

Answer (score 4):

> The JPanel is not visible until Thread.sleep finishes. Why? What am I
>   doing wrong?

- don't block `Event Dispatch Thread`, T`hread.sleep(int)` block EDT, Swing GUI waiting untill this delay ended, and all change made during `Thread.sleep(int)` would not be visible on the screen, use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead, otherwise all changes to the Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`
- Swing is single threaded and all updates to the visible GUI (or stated out of `invokeLater`) must be done on EDT, more in [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: wait, I'm going to modify the question, as this is not the problem really. The sleep is just a desperate test. Forget it

Comment: you have to modify usage of Thread.sleep(), this action required little bit alchemy, great dose of luck and courage, very good knowledge about Java & Swing, examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14834384/714968) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11345662/714968), please take my works as joke, don't do that, otherwise you'll block EDT

Comment: don't waste ..., [here is your answer for JOptionPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641887/swingworker-in-java/12643642#12643642)

Comment: I don't undestand. When is a JPanel shown then? after you call `frame.add(panel)`? after you call `frame.validate()`? or after a random time?

Comment: all changes are done (for already visible container) after `frame.re(in Java7)validate()` and `frame.repaint()`, for changes in the JComponents hierarch to use near container (`JPanel` e.i.) not `JFrame`, but depends if you wan to `re_layout` whole `JFrame` or only some of part(s)

Comment: SSCCE posted. Try to remove the JOptionPane and look at the console

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: mKorbel was right, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513). `JFreeChart` is a _little_ different: it uses AWT events, but it's _not_ a `JComponent` so it can run headless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is solved thanks to invokeLater:

```
public void methodCalledOnceDisplayed() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chartPanel.repaint();
                chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0).getDataArea();
                chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(1).getDataArea();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now there is no `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

An **explanation** of why is this happening would be great

Comment: because you provide hard and long running event out of EDT, then invokeLater to force updates to EDT, repaint could be last code line in code block

Comment: where is that "hard and long running event"?

Comment: As usual, @mKorbel has the correct insight; I've elaborated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513).