# Focusing a JTextArea in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtabbedpane, changelistener

I'm programming a chat client in Java, where I'd like to have one single JDialog for all open chats. So I decided to work with a JTabbedPane where a tab represents a single chat.

I put a JPanel into every tab, which simply contains a JTextPane for the message history and a JTextArea where users input their messages.

For a better usability I implemented a feature that focuses the JTextArea when

1. a new ChatTab is opened
2. the user changes between the ChatTabs (the ChangeListener of the JTabbedPane fires)

I have a class **ChatWindow**, which extends JDialog and displays the JTabbedPane. This is where I implemented the ChangeListener.

```
private JTabbedPane chatTabPane;
private List<ChatTab> chatTabs;

public ChatWindow() {
    chatTabs = new ArrayList<ChatTab>();

    JPanel chatWindowPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    chatTabPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    chatWindowPanel.add(chatTabPane);

    this.add(chatWindowPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    chatTabPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            focusInputField();
        }
    });
}

public ChatTab addChatTab(Contact contact) {
    ChatTab newChatTab = new ChatTab();
    chatTabs.add(newChatTab);
    chatTabPane.addTab(contact.toString(), null, newChatTab.getPanel());
    return newChatTab;
}

public void focusInputField() {
    for (ChatTab chatTab : chatTabs) {
        if(chatTab.getPanel() == chatTabPane.getSelectedComponent()) {
            chatTab.focusInputField();
        }
    }
}

public JTabbedPane getChatTabs() {
    return chatTabPane;
}
}
```

The method *focusInputField()* in the class **ChatTab** simply looks like this:

```
public void focusInputField() {
    inputField.requestFocusInWindow();
    inputField.requestFocus();
}
```

Okay, that's for the focus when the tab is changed. Beside that, I have also implemented that the JTextArea is focused when a new chat tab is created. That is handled in the class **ChatWindowController**. There is a method *setChatVisible()* that I call when I add a new tab to the **ChatWindow** class:

```
public void setChatVisible() {
    if(!chatWindow.isVisible()) {
        chatWindow.setVisible(true);

        chatWindow.focusInputField();
    }
}
```

So here is my problem: The focus works when I open a new chattab. In most cases it also works when the user changes the tabs, BUT it does not focus when I opened more than one new chat tab and switch between the tabs FOR THE FIRST TIME. The JTextArea of the tab where I switched to does not focus. However, when I switch again it works all the time.

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'm really out of ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intermittent failure may result from incorrect synchronization. Several thing should be examined critically:

- Verify that you construct all GUI elements on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT).
- As you are surely using multiple threads, verify that all updates occur on the EDT, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).
- You can use `invokeLater()` to order events on the EDT, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513).
- Prefer [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) over `requestFocus()`, but don't use both.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't consider that the EDT could be the problem. Calling the focusInputField() method in the ChatTab class with EventQueue.invokeLater() solved my problem.