# jfreechart get the index of the dataset from the mouseevent coordinates

Tags: jfreechart

I am working on making some interactions on JFreechart.

The thing we are trying to achieve is to get the index of the value(range and the domain) which is clicked by the mouse. In another words, we want to use the Mouse event to get the index of the data set both for the domain and the range values.

Another thing here is some data we get from xyPlot.getDomainCrosshairValue() is some number like,1.05358272E12 , how could I get the exactly time from this infomation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ChartMouseListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513), and examine the `ChartEntity` found in the `ChartMouseEvent`. You can query your `XYDataset` for details of a particular `XYItemEntity`.