# how to get mouse's y or x axis coordinates in a jfreechart xy plot

Tags: java, mouse, coordinates, jfreechart

i have managed to plot an xy chart with a few points using jfreechart.

what am trying to do is to be able to click anywhere on the line that has been drawn and get its x or y axis value.

Can anybody help me out ?
its my first time using j freechart and i feel somewhat lost.

i created the dataset and generated the chart so far.

```
TimeSeries s = new TimeSeries("security", Day.class);
        while (rate_i.hasNext()) {    
            rate r = (rate) rate_i.next();    
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(r.d);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            s.add(new Day(day, month, year), r.rate);    
        }
        TimeSeriesCollection ds = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        ds.addSeries(s);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                "Security Performance over time.", // title
                "Date", // x-axis label
                "Value", // y-axis label
                ds, // data
                true, // create legend?
                true, // generate tooltips?
                false // generate URLs?
                );
        XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        xyplot.setDomainPannable(true);
        xyplot.setRangePannable(false);
        xyplot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyplot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer xyitemrenderer = xyplot
                .getRenderer();
        if (xyitemrenderer instanceof XYLineAndShapeRenderer) {
            XYLineAndShapeRenderer xylineandshaperenderer = 
                  (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) xyitemrenderer;
            xylineandshaperenderer.setBaseShapesVisible(false);
        }
        DateAxis dateaxis = (DateAxis) xyplot.getDomainAxis();
        dateaxis.setDateFormatOverride(
             new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy"));    
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Chart", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700, 900);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `ChartMouseListener` to your enclosing `ChartPanel`; examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002959/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513). The `ChartEntity` will contain details about the mouse target.

Comment: Thank you, i will investigate that ASAP :)