# Set the size of plots in a CombinedDomain JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I created a `CombinedDomain`/`TimeSeries` chart, but the plots don't have the same size. The ones on the top of the `Panel` are smaller than the one below, as the screenshot shows:

[image: Screenshot of how the chart looks]

Is there any way to set the size of the plots? I want all the plots to be equal in size, no matter if there's 2 plots or 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513), subplots added to a `CombinedDomainXYPlot` are given equal weight. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894894/230513), you can specify the desired weight when you [`add()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html#add-org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot-int-) a subplot.

> The weight determines how much space is allocated to the subplot relative to all the other subplots.

To get equal size, either use the default:

```
plot.add(subplotTop);
plot.add(subplotBottom);
```

or specify equal sizes:

```
plot.add(subplotTop, 1);
plot.add(subplotBottom, 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! Adding "1" with the subplot works. For some reason I didn't have "1" in for every plot...

Comment: @LeonardoBuzzi: Glad it helped.