# How to handle JDialog opened after setVisible(false)?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

This is the scenario:

- add windowOpened() handler to new instance of JDialog
- show dialog for the first time using jdialog.setVisible(true)
- as expected: windowOpened() handler triggered
- jdialog.setVisible(false)
- jdialog.setVisible(true)
- expected, but not happened: windowOpened() handler triggered

How do I handle situation when my modal dialog appeared on the screen whenever it was first time or subsequent times I called setVisible(true) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPanel which one of Listeners is proper for visibility is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed)

Comment: Well... reference is useful, thank you. But it's not a duplicate, since my question is exactly about JDialog, but not anything which a subclass of JComponent

Comment: I considered it a duplicate because your question is a subset of the one I referenced. Either way, glad you have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I handle situation when my modal dialog appeared on the screen
>   whenever it was first time or subsequent times I called
>   setVisible(true) ?

- have to use ComponentListener, and to override methods componentHidden() and componentShown()
- JComponent must returns true from isDisplayable()
- [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed)

Comment: You're really quick =) Thank you!