# JFrame, intercept event when is showed

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe

I have a JFrame that contains dynamic content and

```
my_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

The frame is show only when the user press a JButton and my_frame class contains only a constructor (for fist time invocation) and a refresh method for refreshing its content. 
Now i would that when the JFrame become visibile again, my_frame intercept the event and call automatically the refresh method. How can i do it?

Comment: Take a look at [How to write Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) and [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) for some ideas

Comment: aside `Now i would that when the JFrame become visibile again` != `WindowListener` my view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i would that when the JFrame become visibile again, my_frame
>   intercept the event and call automatically the refresh method. How can
>   i do it?

- good concept, very good idea to re_use one `Top-Level Container`
- I'd suggest to use `JDialog(parent)` instead of `JFrame`
- you can to call `my_frame.setVisible(true)`, by assuming that `my_frame` is declared and initialized as variable
- or `Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();` returns array of `Top-Level Container`, inside loop in this array you can to test  `if (wins[i] instanceof JFrame) {`, then call `wins[i].setVisible(true);`

Comment: thanks. I've found that for do what i need, just add a ComponentListener and use componentShown method of ComponentAdapter for handle the event.

Comment: [see more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed)