# Program not repainting upon JFrame height maximizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

You can resize JFrame with mouse dragging in several ways:

1. You can resize it's height (top/bottom edge)
2. You can resize it's width (left/right edge)
3. You can resize both (in corners)
4. You can maximize it by dragging the whole window to the monitor top edge
5. You can maximize it's height by dragging it's top/bottom edge to the top/bottom edge of the monitor

My program is being repainted on every one of this actions except the number 5.

Why is that?

Could that be bug in my program? It doesn't seem so. I don't know where would I put repaint request for that particular case... It seems that JFrame itself should call repaint on it's contentPane after each resize, right?

It smells like a bug in Java itself, in JFrame class.

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Gui
{
    Gui()
    {
        JFrame masterWindow = new JFrame("My very own SSCCE");

        masterWindow.setSize(1100, 100);
        masterWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        masterWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        masterWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Gui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Grab the top edge of the JFrame and drag it to the top edge of the screen and release. Bottom extended part should be pitch black. If you then maximize it, it will all be grey, as it should.

I still say it's Java or Windows bug.

Comment: `It smells like a bug in Java itself, in JFrame class.` - I doubt it. Like you have been asked in other questions post your `SSCCE` that shows the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug.  Very interesting!  I will give it some thought.

Comment: It think it's bug related to Windows. Since I was expanding only the top part of the JFrame, Java didn't expect the bottom part to be expanded (which is Windows's doing), and didn't repaint it. But then again, if I do the same thing by expanding the JFrame to the bottom, everything is fine... Interesting...

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that was the expected behaviour (to automatically resize vertically to fill the screen). By the way if you drag the bottom edge to the bottom the frame will resize to the top properly. So I agree, it seems like a bug to me. I'm using JDK7 on Windows 7.

Comment: So am I. Yeah, I just noticed it by accident...

Comment: I added a couple of listeners to the frame (ComponentListener, WindowStateListener). No events get fired when the frame size jumps to the bottom, so I guess Java is not receiving/handling this event.

Comment: Can we report the bug somwhere?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 can you  [please to confirm with this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18701252/714968)

Comment: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

Comment: I confirmed. It doesn't work with that code either...

Comment: You could put your "repaint" call into a componentMoved() method of a ComponentAdapter.  But, you really want more than just "repaint".  You need to get the window to re-validate itself by calling invalidate() and validate(), which is what happens after a "normal" window re-sizing event.  I've posted code below as an answer.

Comment: Fixed in Java 8: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/84c766f6796b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the Windows implementation of Java.  (I am also using Windows 7 and JDK7.)

When Windows decides to change the height of the window, a `COMPONENT_MOVED` event is received by Window, but no `COMPONENT_RESIZED` event is received.

Inside the Windows class, the non-public method `dispatchEventImpl()` will respond to `COMPONENT_RESIZED` events by calling `invalidate()` and `validate()`, but it will ignore `COMPONENT_MOVED` events.

Here is a brute-force method of making the window re-validate itself after such an event.  This may occasionally make the window re-validate in other situations, but not very often since the Window class itself is doing re-validation after every `COMPONENT_RESIZED` event, and the reported bug only happens when the window is being actively resized by the user.

```
    masterWindow.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      private int oldWidth = 0;
      private int oldHeight = 0;

      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        oldWidth = masterWindow.getWidth();
        oldHeight = masterWindow.getHeight();
      }

      @Override
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
          if (masterWindow.getWidth() != oldWidth || masterWindow.getHeight() != oldHeight) {
            masterWindow.invalidate();
            masterWindow.validate();
          }
          oldWidth = masterWindow.getWidth();
          oldHeight = masterWindow.getHeight();
      }
    });
```

Comment: +1 but linke code in my comments works for me Win7/8 jdk7_11 and 25, the same as compiled in Java6_whatever

Comment: @mKorbel If you are referring to the code you linked to in a different question, then that is calling `repaint()` every time the component is resized.  But if this window has some non-trivial contents, then it is very likely that it needs to revalidate them.  Ultimately, this looks like a bug that Oracle needs to address.  The window should be sending a `COMPONENT_RESIZED` event, but it is not.

Answer (score 2):

BTW: Action 5 can also be invoked by double-clicking on the top/bottom corner of a window (in Windows 8 at least).

@Enwired: Your solution works only when the window is actually moved during the maximize.
But it does not work, when the window is already at y=0, when invoking the vertical maximize. (I use a little tool called AltDrag which snaps windows to the borders of the screen, which makes this case a lot more likely. But a new window which wasn't moved or repositioned initially might have the same problem.)

I noticed, that when a window is vertically maximized `paint()` is called once on the window.

So a solution for the maximize action would be to override `paint()` and do this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    checkResizeWindow(this);
    super.paint(g);
}

public static void checkResizeWindow(Window window)
{
    if (!window.isShowing())
    {
        return;
    }
    Component[] components = window.getComponents();
    if (components.length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    Component comp = components[0];
    Insets insets = window.getInsets();
    Dimension innerSize = window.getSize();
    innerSize.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
    innerSize.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
    if (!innerSize.equals(comp.getSize()))
    {
        window.invalidate();
        window.validate();
    }
}
```

The calculation i use is to determine if the window actually needs revalidation, by checking the the `innerSize` against the first child component's size (which usually is a single `Panel` filling out the whole `innerSize`).

But, the same original problem still remains for the restore action.
We would have to find an event which is called in that case and also call `checkResizeWindow()` at that point.

I was also thinking about...

- using other events like MouseMotion or Focus, but they occur only later and some might even occur very often which could cause problems with our `checkResizeWindow()` method when being invoked too fast repeatedly.
- using a recurring polling check calling `checkResizeWindow()` on every window, but polling is a bad concept in general and has it's own downsides.