# Creating a Moveable Maximized Window on Windows 7 with Java

Tags: java, windows, swing

I'm looking to create a Window that will be remain maximized, but can be dragged to other screens (where it will maximize again).  My current implementation fails at doing this.

DESIRED BEHAVIOR:

- Window Starts maximized
- Drag window to different monitor
- Window maximizes on that monitor

ACTUAL BEHAVIOR:

- Window starts maximized
- Drag window to different monitor
- Window remains in unmaximized state (though, oddly enough, based on the window icons in the top-right, it looks as if it "thinks" it is maximized)
- If I double-click the window to attempt to maximize it (which I don't want to have to do; this is merely an extended observation), it maximizes on the ORIGINAL screen (not the one it's currently on).

Anyone have any ideas?

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ComponentMovedTest extends JPanel
{
    private ComponentMovedTest()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComponentMovedTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // FIXME: Naive attempt at ensuring the window becomes maximized
        // on the screen it moves to after moving finishes.
        frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved( ComponentEvent e )
            {
                frame.setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
            }
        });

        frame.setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
        frame.setResizable( false );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ComponentMovedTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18725943/15880), but it appears to address a bug in Swing where `COMPONENT_RESIZED` isn't called when you use Windows 7's drag ability to maximize/restore windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went with a hack solution in the end.  I couldn't get the automatic maximization to work in a manner that was acceptable.  I instead made it so that if the window is not maximized, it enforces a strict size, but still allows you to manually maximize the window.  The hack solution is below.  I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer in a few days if no one has a solution closer to the intent of the original question.

Hack Example Fix:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ComponentMovedTest extends JPanel
{
    Dimension size = new Dimension( 0, 0 );

    private ComponentMovedTest()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "ComponentMovedTest" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // NOTE: With a proper layout manager, this ComponentListener may
        //       not be necessary, as the layout manager would likely enforce
        //       minimum/maximum window sizing.  This means fix #2 could
        //       also be removed in favor of setting min/max/pref size,
        //       based on the layout manager.
        frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized( ComponentEvent e )
            {
                if (frame.getExtendedState() != JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                {
                    // FIX #3: resize the window to the default size
                    //         whenever resized.
                    frame.setSize(size);
                }
            }
        });

        // FIX #1: Extend after setting visible.
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );

        // FIX #2: Set a default window size.
        size = frame.getSize();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new ComponentMovedTest();
    }
}
```