# Non-Terminating Window Listener From Parent Class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose, windowlistener

Can anyone explain why the following program does not terminate when closing the child window?

I have created a simple application with a parent `JFrame` that instantiates a child class with a `JDialog`. When I pass the parent reference into the child class so that the `JDialog` can be created with a parent (ie: `new JDialog(parent);`), the window listener that is added to it from the parent class causes the program to never terminate once the child window has been closed. The windows do indeed close (in terms of visibility), but the program itself still runs. The default close operation for the parent is set to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. The default close operation for the child is set to `JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

If I pass no parent reference to the child class so that the `JDialog` is instantiated without a parent window, the example does terminate when the child window is closed. For instance, the program terminates if the following is used: `ChildWindow prompt = new ChildWindow(null);`

Parent Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ParentWindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    private JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Open Child Window!");

    public ParentWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ChildWindow prompt = new ChildWindow(frame); // or use null for no parent

                prompt.getDialog().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
                        // .. get some information from the child before disposing 
                        System.out.println("Window closed."); // does not terminate when passing frame as parent
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new ParentWindow();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChildWindow {
    private JDialog dialog;
    private JButton okButton = new JButton("Close");

    public ChildWindow(Window parent) {
        dialog = new JDialog(parent);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.getContentPane().add(okButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JDialog getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Window closed.
Window closed.
Window closed.
... (does not terminate)
```

Comment: Works just fine for me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Did you try closing the child window?

Comment: Yep, opened 3, closed the first...waited a second or two and the JVM terminated...

Comment: @MadProgrammer When I run it the program definitely terminates when the parent window is closed but if I close any child window it gets stuck and does not terminate (using either the child window's close button or the `JButton` close button).

Comment: What OS, what Java version?

Comment: Windows 8.1 (x64) and initially tried on JDK1.7u55 (x64). I get the same results on JDK1.7u60 x64 and x86.

Comment: Well, I can tell you works fine on Windows 7 and Java 8...buuuutttt...not with Java 7....

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, even when I use null as the parent. I use Windows 7, but am confused about my Java version. I thought I just updated 3 days ago to the current version. When I go to the "Control Panel" and click on the "Java 32 bit" Icon and then click the "About" button on the "General" tab it says I am using "Java Version 7 - Update 60" which makes sense. But when I run Java from the command line and use "java -version" it still says I'm using 'java version "1.7.0_10"'. So I'm confused? How do you know you are running "JDK1.7u55 (x64)."? What command to you use for that info?

Comment: I have my IDE setup that way ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right, it does work in Java 8 (JDK1.8.0u05)!

Comment: @camickr I am using Eclipse and it says in the Project's Build Path and directly above the Console window which JDK I'm using.

Comment: @CanadianDavid, thanks. I guess I'll have to learn how to use an IDE one of these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested using Windows 7 and Java 8 and had not issues, when I tried Java 7 or Java 6, it simply kept on printing out `Window Closed.`...

So, I updated the `windowClosed` method using a test for `frame.isVisible`

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ChildWindow prompt = new ChildWindow(frame); // or use null for no parent

        prompt.getDialog().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                // .. get some information from the child before disposing 
                System.out.println("Window closed."); // does not terminate when passing frame as parent
                if (frame.isVisible()) {
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And got it to work...now to see if I can find out why...

I "think" what's happening is this...

1. `okButton` is triggered, `dialog.dispose` is called
2. `dialog.dispose` is setting up the first `windowClosed` event
3. The `WindowListener` is been notified of the `windowClosed` event, which is disposing of the frame...
4. The frame is trying to close it's child windows, which is causing the dialogs to notify the `WindowListener` AGAIN that they are closing and so forth...goto 3 and repeat...

This is a bug, which appears to be fixed in Java 8...Because the closing events are been pushed onto the Event Queue, you won't get a `StackOverflowException`...

In this case, another option would be to remove the `WindowListener` from the `Window` that triggered the `windowClosed` event...

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ChildWindow prompt = new ChildWindow(frame); // or use null for no parent

        prompt.getDialog().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                e.getWindow().removeWindowListener(this);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works here too, except in my environment with JDK1.7u60 it prints it out twice. With JDK1.8u5 it works as expected and prints only once.

Comment: Interesting find, thanks. Since it's a modeless dialog that is created, is there a better way to get information (externally from another class) from the dialog when it has closed?

Comment: issue is that last turn of the light (JVM)

Comment: @CanadianDavid [those two threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed) would be [interesting...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309407/remove-top-level-container-on-runtime)