# Java Swing: ScrollableTooltip vs ContextMenu

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, hidden, scrollable

I'm working on a (legacy) Java-Swing application and ran into a problem:

The main GUI-component in this application is a Gantt chart, that displays tasks, as rectangles with a label, basically.
A right-click on a task opens a context-menu, while hovering over a task with the mouse will show a customized, scrollable JTooltip. This constellation leads to my problem.

If I position the tool-tip too far away from the current mouse position, the tool-tip disappears, before I can move the mouse to one of the scroll-bar handles (horizontal/vertical).
If I position the tool-tip too near to the current mouse position, the context menu won't open anymore, because the tool-tip hides the underlying task and the right-click is therefore captured by the tool-tip and not the task.

What I've tried so far:

- searched for some kind of delay in ToolTipManager, to control how long the tool-tip is shown, after the mouse leaves the control, which triggered the tool-tip to be shown. As far as I can say, there is no such delay-property.
- tried to find the right distance between tool-tip and current mouse position, so that the scroll-bar handles of the tool-tip can be reached and the context-menu is also shown. -> I found some distance, where both works, but often you have to try several times, until one can reach the scroll-bar handles.

So my question is:
Is there any way to control when a JToolTip is hidden after the mouse leaves the corresponding component?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

- create `JWindow`, better undecorated `JDialog` with correct modality (then could be easiest to catch `MouseEvents)`
- only one window with [setDefaultCloseOperation-DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE or HIDE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29), by toggling only with `setVisible false / true`, to reuse this container for whole JVM instance, clear windows content before is `setVisible(false)` called
- put there `Swing Timer` with (for example) 5-10 seconds for logical autoclosing, by testing `SwingTimer.isRunning`, if Mouse Scrolling continues and `SwingTimer.isRunning` returns `true` then to call `SwingTimer.restart`
- override `mouseClicked` for whole JVM instance e.g.

  ```
  if (window.isVisible)
      window.getContentPane.removeAll() 
      window.setVisible(false)
  else
      someThingWithRealEventFromMouseListener
  ```
- there can be used [some of better Listener that returns Boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed) instead of using low level instance of MouseListener
- you can to `(re)dispatch()` mouse scrolling (only inside of Bound of the current parent - `JFrame`, `JDialog`) to the popup window, by using two - three methods from [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html)